# Artisan migrate showing error in the server for a fresh project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have uploaded my Laravel 5.5 project to the centOS7 server. Now I am facing the following error when I am running "php artisan migrate" for the first time to load database table.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeo8e.jpg)

Here is my .env db section

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=event
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=testpass
```

I have created the DB in the MySQL.

```
[root@li129-226 event_management]# php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 664:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown    to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = event and table_name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 67:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

In Connector.php line 67:
PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392

Answer (score 3):

What I did that worked really well was to just alter the root user to have a password. Log in to mysql on the terminal then do this command:

`ALTER USER 'user'@'address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword'`

for the user, I used `'root'@'localhost'` You may want to use a different user.

Then, replace `DB_PASSWORD=yourpassword` with the password you chose in the command above and save the file.

That allowed me to run `php artisan migrate` and everything worked great!